# Crystal reports formatting issue with formula fields

Tags: formatting, crystal-reports

I am writing a crytal report with the following stucture:

```
Group 1: School
    Group 2: Student
        Group 3: Category
            Details
```

I am trying to split the details into two seperate columns with formula fields.  This is working fine except, one of the formula fields is printing below the other, and I can't figure out how to make them print on the same level.

It looks like this:

```
Category A       Category B
detail 1
detail 2
                detail 1
                detail 2
                detail 3
```

I want it to look like this:

```
Category A       Category B
detail 1         detail 1
detail 2         detail 2
                 detail 3
```

I feel like I'm missing something very simple, can anyone help me!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is not something simple.  The problem is that, since the data is grouped on the categories, it will show all of one category before any of the next one.  Even if you take out the grouping by category, you'll still end up with data like:

```
Category A      Category B
detail 1
                detail 1
                detail 2
detail 2
                detail 3
```

There is a way to get it exactly the way you want it, but the whole set of results under each category would be put into one field per category.  That is not an issue if you are printing or viewing it on screen, but  exporting to Excel would put each column into one cell each; like so:

```
Category A      Category B
+---------+     +---------+
|detail 1 |     |detail 1 |
|detail 2 |     |detail 2 |
+---------+     |detail 3 |
                +---------+
```

To do that, we would create what is basically a text running-total field (or two of them).  First, an initializer in the report header:

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
Global StringVar CatA := "";
Global StringVar CatB := "";
""; //print nothing on screen
```

Then, an updater in the details section.  The details section itself would actually be hidden (**not** suppressed).

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
Global StringVar CatA;
Global StringVar CatB;

If {Table.Category} = "Category A"
    //Chr(10) + Chr(13) is a return/newline
    Then CatA := CatA + Chr(10) + Chr(13) + {Table.Detail};

If {Table.Category} = "Category B"
    Then CatB := CatB + Chr(10) + Chr(13) + {Table.Detail};

""; //print nothing
```

Finally, after everything related to the category is done (I would assume in the *Group 2: Student* footer), print the results of the global variables.  So, for category A:

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
Global StringVar CatA;
```

You will have to make sure the result fields are set to `Can grow`.

Comment: EvilBob, that is a great answer!  I'm going to work on a version that implements your thoughts above.  I ended up using subreports, but I have six of them, so as you can guess it runs very slow!!  Hopefully, your way will work much faster.